# New construction built on frozen ground = house settling 3" from north to south

Tags: foundation

We are in the process of building a new home. Our foundation and framing guy built through the winter, assuring us that they install wood basements all year. We have a wood basement with a wood floor and a 2" x 6" framed home on the wood basement foundation.  The frost has come out of the ground and our house has "settled" 3" on one whole side.  Our house is designed to load at 2,000 Psf and our soil (sand) supports 4,000 Psf so it's not a soil problem. Any suggestions? I just need my floors to be level!

Answer (score 3):

Get your foundation and framing guy to deal with it. It should be his problem, since it's certainly his fault.

That may take your contract (one hopes it has appropriate language) and a lawyer, or not, depending on how much integrity he does or does not have.

Comment: Thanks. He's a little short on integrity. We will have to pay thousands and time for a lawyer and an engineer or just fix it ourselves. I'm not sure how to maneuver in these waters!

Comment: In your answer below, you (the OP) talk about purlins. I would not in a million years accept that as a solution. Your east/west windows will be screwed up, and more importantly, you've taken a massive bite out of your equity by not having this fixed. Seriously, lawyer up. Have the house made level, walk away, or pay 10 cents on the dollar for it, because that's all you're going to get back (and, if applicable, all the bank is going to give you when they realize what they're putting money into).

Answer (score 0):

I've spoken with an engineer and convinced it was frozen pea stone. We're considering purlins on the floor to make up 2" of the slope. We will have to reset the front door and stairs, but don't think much else will be affected. Am I missing anything? I'm waiting a call back from a lawyer. Thank you!